# mysql CASE WHEN either but not both

Tags: mysql, case

I have a case statement:

```
case when R1 = risk_factor OR R2 = risk_factor then 1 else 0 end
```

but it also picks up

```
case when R1 = risk_factor AND R2 = risk_factor then 1 else 0 end
```

What is the correct syntax to state:

```
case when (R1 = risk_factor or R2 = risk_factor) BUT NOT (R1 = risk_factor AND R2 = risk_factor) then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(R1 = risk_factor or R2 = risk_factor) BUT NOT (R1 = risk_factor AND R2 = risk_factor)
```

should be

```
(R1 = risk_factor or R2 = risk_factor) AND NOT (R1 = risk_factor AND R2 = risk_factor)
```

But you can also use `XOR`

```
(R1 = risk_factor XOR R2 = risk_factor)
```

> Logical XOR. Returns NULL if either operand is NULL. For non-NULL
>   operands, evaluates to 1 if an odd number of operands is nonzero,
>   otherwise 0 is returned.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor)

However - In yor specific case you can also write the condition as

```
(risk_factor IN (R1, R2) AND R1 <> R2)
```

Note: If your CASE expression is like `then 1 else 0`, then you don't need it at all. You can just use the boolean expression. With one exception: If your boolean expression can return NULL and you want to convert it to `0`. But in that case you can also use `COALESCE(boolean_expression, 0)`.

Comment: like the 'XOR' operator

Comment: @hb so from now on you will be able to recognise the XOR pattern, which is good!

Answer (score 2):

You have to start with the "hardest" condition

```
case when (R1 = risk_factor AND R2 = risk_factor) then 0
     when (R1 = risk_factor  OR R2 = risk_factor) then 1 
     else 0 
end
```